# bash: /dev/scull: No such device or address

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, drivers

I`m trying to type simple scull device driver, and have the next issue.

1. I build kernel module.
2. `insmod scull.ko`
3. Check `/var/log/kern.log` major: 245 number and minor: 0 number.
4. Created device file: `mknod /dev/scull 245 0`
5. Try to type `cat /dev/scull` got a bash error.

What i did in mistake, please help. Maybe i forgot something.

kernel log

```
Apr 14 19:17:14 XLDD kernel: [ 5765.234335] SCULL: device number registration...
Apr 14 19:17:14 XLDD kernel: [ 5765.234349] SCULL: debug, scull_init 34 device: F500000 MAJOR: 245 MINOR: 0 count: 1
Apr 14 19:17:14 XLDD kernel: [ 5765.234353] SCULL: success device registration
Apr 14 19:17:15 XLDD kernel: [ 5766.384094] SCULL: device number unregistration...
Apr 14 19:17:15 XLDD kernel: [ 5766.384109] SCULL: debug, scull_exit 66 device: F500000 MAJOR: 245 MINOR: 0 count: 1
Apr 14 19:17:15 XLDD kernel: [ 5766.384113] SCULL: done device registration
```

I try to do:

```
root@XLDD:/usr/src# make
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic M=`pwd`
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-42-generic'
root@XLDD:/usr/src# insmod scull.ko 
root@XLDD:/usr/src# mknod /dev/scull c 245 0
root@XLDD:/usr/src# echo "Hello" > /dev/scull
bash: /dev/scull: No such device or address
root@XLDD:/usr/src#
```

scull.c

```
#include <linux/module.h> /* MODULE_LICENSE() MODULE_AUTHOR() */
#include <linux/init.h>   /* init() exit()                    */
#include <linux/types.h>  /* Used for uint8 e.t.c types       */
#include <linux/kdev_t.h> /* Undefined what it is for         */
#include <linux/fs.h>     /* Used for working with inode      */
#include <linux/errno.h>  /* Used for errors handling         */
#include <linux/cdev.h>   /* Used for device registration     */
#include "scull.h"
#include "scull_operations.h"
#include "scull_helpers.h"


static int scull_init(void)
{
    int alloc_result = 0;
    /*!
     * Character device registration:
     * 0        - success
     * negative - unsuccess
     */
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: device number registration...\n");
    alloc_result = alloc_chrdev_region(&scull_dev.dev, SCULL_DEV_FIRSTMIRROR, SCULL_DEV_COUNT,SCULL_DEV_NAME);

    /*!
     * Checking character device number registration
     */
    if(alloc_result != 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: unsuccess device number registration error code:%d\n",alloc_result);
    }
    else
    {
#ifdef SCULL_DEBUG
        printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: debug, %s %d device: %X MAJOR: %d MINOR: %d count: %u\n",__func__,__LINE__,scull_dev.dev,MAJOR(scull_dev.dev),MINOR(scull_dev.dev),SCULL_DEV_COUNT);
#endif /* SCULL_DEBUG */
        printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: success device registration\n");
    }
    /*!
     * Filling scull file operations
     */
    scull_fops.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    scull_fops.open  = scull_open;
    scull_fops.read  = scull_read;
    scull_fops.write = scull_write;
    /*!
     * Initialize a scull_dev structure
     * remembering fops, making it ready to add to the system with cdev_add
     */
    cdev_init(&scull_cdev, &scull_fops);


    return 0;
}

static void scull_exit(void)
{
    /*!
     * Remove a character device from the system
     */
    cdev_del(&scull_cdev); /*!< Remove a character device from the system */
    /*!
     * Character device number unregistration:
     */
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: device number unregistration...\n");
#ifdef SCULL_DEBUG
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: debug, %s %d device: %X MAJOR: %d MINOR: %d count: %u\n",__func__,__LINE__,scull_dev.dev,MAJOR(scull_dev.dev),MINOR(scull_dev.dev),SCULL_DEV_COUNT);
#endif /* SCULL_DEBUG */
    unregister_chrdev_region(scull_dev.dev, SCULL_DEV_COUNT);   /*!< Character device number unregistration */
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: done device registration\n");

}

module_init(scull_init);
module_exit(scull_exit);
```

scull.h

```
#ifndef SCULL_CONFIG_H
#define SCULL_CONFIG_H

#include <linux/types.h>  /* struct dev_t */
#include <linux/fs.h>     /* file operations */
#include <linux/cdev.h>   /* struct cdev */


#define SCULL_DEV_COUNT       1
#define SCULL_DEV_NAME        "scull"
#define SCULL_DEV_FIRSTMIRROR 0

MODULE_LICENSE("GNU");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Andriy Veres");

/*!
 * data, that store big (12 bits) and little (20 bits)
 * device numbers (driver and device numbers correspondly).
 *
 */       

struct cdev            scull_cdev;
struct file_operations scull_fops;

struct scull_dev {
dev_t     dev;            /* used for device registration */
//struct scull_qset * data;        /* Pointer to first quantum */
//int                 quantum;     /* Size of current quantum */
//int                 qset;        /* Size of quantum set  */
//unsigned long       size;        /* Size of data stored hear */
//unsigned int        access_key;  /* used by sculluid and scullpriv */
//struct semaphore    sem;         /* Semaphore both exeption */
//struct cdev         cdev;        /* Symbol device structure */
}scull_dev;

/*!
 * Uncomment for debug
 */
#define SCULL_DEBUG

#endif /* SCULL_CONFIG_H */
```

scull_helpers.c

```
#include "scull_helpers.h"

int scull_trim(scull_dev * dev)
{
#ifdef SCULL_DEBUG
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: debug, %s %d device: \n",__func__,__LINE__);
#endif /* SCULL_DEBUG */
    return 0;
}
```

scull_helpers.h

```
    #ifndef SCULL_HELPERS_H
    #define SCULL_HELPERS_H
    #include "scull.h"
    int scull_trim(struct scull_dev * dev);
    #endif /* SCULL_HELPERS_H */
```

scull_operations.c

```
#include "scull_operations.h"

int scull_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
#ifdef SCULL_DEBUG
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: debug, %s\n",__func__,__LINE__);
#endif /* SCULL_DEBUG */
    return 0;   /* success */
}


int scull_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
#ifdef SCULL_DEBUG
    printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: debug, %s\n",__func__,__LINE__);
#endif /* SCULL_DEBUG */
    return 0;
}

ssize_t scull_read(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
     ssize_t result = count;
#ifdef SCULL_DEBUG
     printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: debug, %s result: %d\n",__func__,__LINE__,result);
#endif /* SCULL_DEBUG */

     return result;
}

ssize_t scull_write(struct file *filp, const char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    ssize_t result = count;
#ifdef SCULL_DEBUG
         printk(KERN_ALERT "SCULL: debug, %s result: %d\n",__func__,__LINE__,result);
#endif /* SCULL_DEBUG */

    return result;
}
```

scull_helpers.h

```
#ifndef SCULL_OPEARATIONS_H
#define SCULL_OPEARATIONS_H
int (*scull_open) (struct inode *, struct file *);
int (*scull_release) (struct inode *, struct file *);
ssize_t (*scull_read) (struct file *, char *, size_t, loff_t *);
ssize_t (*scull_write) (struct file *, const char *, size_t, loff_t *);
#endif /* SCULL_OPERATIONS_H */
```

Comment: Can you also post results of `strace cat /dev/scull`?

Comment: Is this exactly the `kern.log` after your `insmod`? Because I can see the module being unregistered. The last log line from `exit` function is confusing, because it should say "done device **un**registration"

Comment: Hello, osgx, viraptor, thanks a lot for responding. When i copied code to question i changed "registration" to "unregistration", sorry. I founded the reason, i forgot [cdev_add](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-cdev-add.html)