# How to build external modules in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am trying to build a scull device, and have build a `.ko` file without problem. But when `insmod`ed, then `cat` of `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
May 14 00:33:06 XLM kernel: [ 4251.407594] scull: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
May 14 00:33:06 XLM kernel: [ 4251.407680] scull: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
```

So therefor this error occured [bash: /dev/scull: No such device or address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49834997/bash-dev-scull-no-such-device-or-address) (because I have tried to write to `/dev/scull0` after `mknod /dev/scull 245 0`,. But as seen from `log`, I have not even register the device, because the module is marked as `out-of-tree` and also `no signature`.) I do not know why I have signature enabled, when I have disable [secure boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773734/how-to-install-module-ko-module-without-kernel-signature-or-kernel-rebuild-in-ub) in bios. Nevertheless, how can I enable kernel to accept the module in order to use the device? I have `MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");` in source, so the licensing should not be the problem.

Comment: Did the module fail to load? Does the module's _init_ function get called (you can check by adding a `printk` in the init function to write something to the kernel log)?

Comment: @IanAbbott, no need to repeat `printk()` that core already have, simple add *initcall_debug* to the kernel command line.

Comment: You need to sign it, basically in the same way as Ubuntu does. But I have no idea where to get the key (I only know you may rebuilt kernel without this feature).

Comment: @0andriy I don't think Ubuntu signed kernels _enforce_ module signature verification unless running in a secure boot environment, but will issue a warning. That's why I wanted to know if the module's init function was being called.

Comment: @IanAbbott, @0andriy, I have added printk to `scull_init_module`, but it did not load, because no output in kern.log. Question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019834/why-does-module-failed-to-load-dev-scull0-no-such-device-or-address

Comment: @autistic456 Stuff may get filtered out of kern.log depending on the loglevel of the message. You can run `dmesg` to see the unfiltered, recent messages.

Comment: @IanAbbott edditted it, take a look