# Why does module failed to load? (/dev/scull0 : no such device or address)

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, chardev

From my previous question: [How to build external modules in ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61798226/how-to-build-external-modules-in-ubuntu?noredirect=1#comment109338772_61798226) I thought I cannot load module due to `loading out-of-tree` or `tainting kernel`, but to my `scull_init_module` (source below) I have added `printk` so I know I get loaded from kern log. But I did not (no output in the log -- the log is the same as from the link).

`uname -a` == `4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2 (2020-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux` (no use of ubuntu - as from the link).

`scull_init_module`:

```
#ifndef scull_major
#define scull_major 0
#endif

#ifndef scull_nr_devs
#define scull_nr_devs 4
#endif

struct scull_dev *scull_devices; /*array of active devices */
static void scull_setup_cdev(struct scull_dev *, int); /*helper function (internal) */  
int scull_minor = 0;


int scull_init_module(void) {
   int i;
   dev_t dev = 0; 
   /* register devices */
   int result = 1;
   result = alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, scull_minor, scull_nr_devs, "scull"); /**comment later**/
   printk(KERN_ALERT"Passed %s %d \n in scull_init_module\n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);

   if(result < 0){
      printk(KERN_WARNING "scull: can't get major %d\n", scull_major);
      return result;
   }

   /* allocate space for devices */ 
   scull_devices = kmalloc(sizeof(struct scull_dev) * scull_nr_devs, GFP_KERNEL);
   if(!scull_devices){
      result = -1;
      goto fail;
   }

   /*initilization of devices */
   for(i=0; i<scull_nr_devs;i++){
      scull_devices[i].quantum = scull_quantum;
      scull_devices[i].qset = scull_qset;
      scull_setup_cdev(&scull_devices[i], i);
   }

   return 0;
   fail:
      scull_cleanup_module();
      return result;
}

module_init(scull_init_module);
```

It is basically from [Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), chapter3. But I hand-write it (no copy/paste). `alloc_chrdev_region` is called properly, so is `scull_setup_cdev`, then where could be problem?

EDIT (output from dmesg):
From `dmesg` it looks like it does load the module:

```
[ 2765.707018] scull: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 2765.707106] scull: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 2765.707929] Passed scull_init_module 41 
                in scull_init_module
```

But then still the node in `/dev/scull0` gives `No such device or address`

```
#mknod /dev/scull0 c 241 0
#cat /dev/scull0
cat: /dev/scull0: No such device or address
```

So if the device is properly registered (see dmesg) and I create node in /dev hierarchy, then what does mean `no device or address`? And why I am getting it?

EDIT2 (function scull_setup_cdev):

```
static void scull_setup_cdev(struct scull_dev *dev, int index){
    int err, devno=MKDEV(scull_major, scull_minor + index);

    cdev_init(&dev->cdev, &scull_fops);
    dev->cdev.owner = THIS_MODULE;
    dev->cdev.ops = &scull_fops; /**comment later**/
    err = cdev_add(&dev->cdev, devno, 1);   
    if (err) 
        printk(KERN_NOTICE "Error %d adding scull%d", err, index);
}
```

Comment: You should add a `\n` to the end of the printk message to force it out. Otherwise, it may get combined with the next message.

Comment: @IanAbbott edditted my post

Comment: How do you know the major device number 241 is correct? Does it match the number in "/proc/devices" for "scull"? Also, what does `scull_setup_cdev()` do and where does it get the major device number from?

Comment: @IanAbbott, the major number is gained from /proc/devices (`#grep scull /proc/devices`, before `mknod`). And I will add the `scull_setup_cdev()` function

Comment: Before you've posted the `scull_setup_cdev()` function source, my guess is that you should have called it as `scull_setup_cdev(&scull_devices[i], dev + i);`, but we'll find out.

Comment: @IanAbbott thats right, it is called exactly like that

Comment: Well no, I guessed wrong, you are passing the index. The problem is that `scull_major` is still 0. Since the chardev region was allocated dynamically, you should have assigned `scull_major = MAJOR(dev);` between the call to `alloc_chrdev_region()` and the `for` loop.

Comment: @IanAbbott it helped, so very thanks, unfortunatelly it caused another problem (from `dmesg`) and I made another question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62022484/kernel-output-weird-dmesg-of-my-driver-module