# kernel output weird dmesg of my driver module

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, kernel-module, chardev

from my previsou question [Why does module failed to load? (/dev/scull0 : no such device or address)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62019834/why-does-module-failed-to-load-dev-scull0-no-such-device-or-address?noredirect=1#comment109694670_62019834) I managed to load the module via `/sbin/insmod`, but after that, I have log out the dmesg:

```
[ 2765.707018] scull: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[ 2765.707106] scull: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[ 2765.707929] Passed scull_init_module at 41 (debug info - successful load of init module)
[ 6027.843914] acer_wmi: Unknown function number - 8 - 1
[ 7347.683312] stack segment: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
[ 7347.683323] CPU: 3 PID: 15280 Comm: rmmod Tainted: G           OE     4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.118-2
[ 7347.683326] Hardware name: Acer Swift SF314-52/Suntory_KL, BIOS V1.08 11/28/2017
/* start of the problem: */
[ 7347.683335] RIP: 0010:scull_trim+0x3a/0xa0 [scull]
[ 7347.683339] Code: 44 8b 77 0c 48 8b 2f 45 8d 66 ff 49 c1 e4 03 48 85 ed 75 16 eb 4b 48 8b 5d 08 48 89 ef e8 7e 38 f1 e1 48 89 dd 48 85 db 74 37 <48> 8b 7d 00 48 85 ff 74 e3 45 85 f6 7e 1a 31 db eb 04 48 83 c3 08

/*... output of all registers ...*/

[ 7347.683372] Call Trace:
[ 7347.683382]  cleanup_module+0x44/0x80 [scull]
[ 7347.683391]  __x64_sys_delete_module+0x190/0x2e0
[ 7347.683399]  do_syscall_64+0x53/0x110
[ 7347.683405]  entry_SYSCALL_64_after_hwframe+0x44/0xa9
[ 7347.683530] ---[ end trace c4b4a1cdb428d4b3 ]---
[ 7347.885914] RIP: 0010:scull_trim+0x3a/0xa0 [scull]
... /* again */ ...
```

Here I can observer, the mess is caused by the `scull_trim` (source below), and kernel trigger `strace` to resolve it (or does kernel call `Call Trace:` when something goes bad in kernel?).

`scull_trim`:

```
 /*main structure */
 struct scull_dev {
 struct scull_qset *data; /*quantum repre*/
 int quantum; /*in bytes*/
 int qset; /*array size*/
 unsigned long size; /*total bytes in device*/
 struct cdev cdev; /*Char device structure*/
 };

/*representation of quantum*/
struct scull_qset {
void **data;
struct scull_qset *next;
};

/*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int scull_trim(struct scull_dev *dev) {
    struct scull_qset *next, *dptr; /* next for loop, dptr = data pointer (index in loop) */
    int qset = dev->qset; /* get size of arrat */
    int i; /*index for second loop for quantum bytes */

    for(dptr = dev->data /*struct scull_qset*/; dptr ; dptr = next){
        if (dptr->data /*array of quantum*/) {
            for(i=0; i<qset; i++){
                kfree(dptr->data[i]); /*free each byte of array data[i]*/
            }
            kfree(dptr->data); /*free array pointer itself*/
            dptr->data = NULL; /*set array pointer to null pointer to avoid garbage*/
        }
        next = dptr->next;
        kfree(dptr); /* free pointer itself */
    }
    //setting new attributes for cleared dev
    dev->size = 0;
    dev->quantum = scull_quantum;
    dev->qset = scull_qset;
    dev->data = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

The function `scull_trim` is basically from [linux device driver, 3 edition](https://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3/), And the function's intend is to get rid of all bytes from the device before `open` method is called. But why does it caused the `dmesg` error in that, kernel had to call strace to resolve it?

EDIT:
Because it is nearly impossible to resolve the problem, I am adding source (as well as dmesg dump) from github:
[repo:scull device](https://github.com/autistic456/scull-device). Please visit it to resolve the issue.

Comment: What lines come before `[ 7347.683335] RIP: 0010:scull_trim+0x3a/0xa0 [scull]`?

Comment: @ThomasJager editted, But it is not interesting the above information (before the first mention of `scull_trim`,  since thay are outputs from other modules)

Comment: That stuff above still seems like part of a dump after an error. Just because it doesn't mention `scull_trim` doesn't mean that it's not related. Is there any more between those messages?

Comment: No, there is no other message in between. I suspect I have created some kind of loop of allocating memory for the devices, but I cannot resolve it from the code (I do not see where the problem comes from). But the dmesg is full now (from the first mention of the module - `scull_init_module`, until its end via force call of `cleanup_module`

Comment: "I suspect I have created some kind of loop of allocating memory for the devices, but I cannot resolve it from the code ..." - Have you tried to **debug** the problem? E.g. insert `printk` into `for` loop and print some information at each iteration. The record `scull_trim+0x3a/0xa0` in the trace means that faulted instruction is at `0x3a` offset from the start of `scull_trim` function. Disassembler your module (`objdump -Sdlr <your-module>.ko > <your-module>.asm`) and find at least **exact line** in your C code which cause the fault.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, you can do it from `Code:` line.   Result for above: `2a:*  48 8b 7d 00             mov    0x0(%rbp),%rdi           <-- trapping instruction`.

Comment: Do you initialize `dev->data = NULL;` and `dev->size = 0;`? I never saw that in your previous question.

Comment: `kfree(dptr->data[i]); /*free each byte of array data[i]*/` comment here is very suspicious. Are you sure you understand what you are doing?

Comment: @0andriy: The `Code` line contains only instruction, not a line in a C code. As for the whole code, it is taken from the LDD3 book, and this comment `free each byte of array data[i]` could be from the book too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, `Code:` contains pretty much enough to assume the issue.

Comment: @0andriy: "`Code:` contains pretty much enough to assume the issue." - Yes, it contain much info ... for one who could **understand the asm** quite good. I suggested an approach which could be used in debug even without high knowledge of asm. BTW, the decoded instruction is for loading (AT&T) from the (most *likely*) the first structure's field. But the code has several lines which could perform such loading. Yes, you could find more "signs" about possible correspondence to C code. But again, it requires great experience in asm.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I have added github repo with source and the dmesg error file. Please visit it, to find out: https://github.com/autistic456/scull-device

Comment: As @IanAbbott noted in the comment, `dev->data` is **never been initialized**. Would you compare your code with [original example of scull driver](https://github.com/martinezjavier/ldd3/blob/master/scull/main.c), you will find the line `memset(scull_devices, 0, scull_nr_devs * sizeof(struct scull_dev));` in the original code. Exactly this line is responsible for zero-initialization of some fields of `scull_dev` structure.

Comment: @IanAbbott, why is needed to memset the memory from kmalloc (I know -> the memory is unitilized and have undeterminate value), but in the next step, I am assigning to each memory element (typeof struct scull_dev) its values -> and thus initializing it. Why is neede the pre-step of zeroing the garbage, when after that I am assigning (in the for loop `for(i=0;i<scull_nr_devs;i++)...`) and thus initializing it there. So why the memset? 2) anyway -> I fix that -> look at repo: https://github.com/autistic456/scull-device

Comment: @autistic456 You are not assigning `scull_devices[i].data = NULL;` in that `for` loop. Its value will be indeterminate when `scull_trim()` or `scull_follow()` is called.

Comment: @autistic456 My previous comment refers to the code before you added the `memset()` call. The `memset` will set `scull_devices[i].data` to `NULL` so you don't need to assign it explicitly.